# Can I install Linux 64bit OS on VMware workstation player 12?

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, vmware-workstation

Simple question. My hardware/software setup is the following:

8GB RAM
2.5 GHz
Windows 8.1 64 bit
VMWare workstation player 12.

Can I install and run 64 bit Linux distributions on my setup? If yes, what should I do different compared to the 32 bit versions?

So far I've only used 32 bit distros since I didn't really need the 64 bit. However, OpenSuSE is only available as a 64 bit and I couldn't install it since it detects a 32 bit hardware at the startup.

Comment: `I couldn't install it since it detects a 32 bit hardware at the startup.` <- that is your answer.

Comment: So your hardware and host OS (Windows) are all 64 bit? This should not be a problem.

Comment: @Hannu yeah but either I have 64 bit hardware or the box, the vendor and Microsoft are telling lies :)

Comment: So what **is** your hardware. Please [edit] and add this to your question.

Comment: Your question is too broad in its current state.  How you run a 64-bit guest os is well documented.  Does your hardware support VT-x if it does not what you want IS NOT POSSIBLE. Edit your question, so not submit commentary, to clarify your question

Comment: @Ramhound The answer below helped me understanding what to check since I was totally unaware of that procedure and where to find it. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running a 64-bit host OS then by definition you have 64-bit hardware. The most likely problem is that you have not enabled, or your CPU does not support, virtualization support as explained [here](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws80/doc/releasenotes_workstation_80.html#Installation_Requirements):

> Installation Requirements
>
> When you install Workstation, the installer performs checks to make
>   sure the host system has a processor that meets the following
>   requirements. You cannot install Workstation if the host system does
>   not meet these requirements.
>
> - 64-bit x86 CPU
> - LAHF/SAHF support in long mode
>
> You can use CPU-Z or a similar utility to determine if the host system
>   CPU is 64-bit capable. CPU-Z shows EM64T (Intel) or AMD64 (AMD) if the
>   processor is 64-bit capable.
>
> If you plan to install a 64-bit guest operating system in a virtual
>   machine, the host system must have one of the following processors.
>   Workstation will not allow you to install a 64-bit guest operating
>   system if the host system does not have one of these processors.
>
> - AMD CPU that has segment-limit support in long mode.
> - Intel CPU that has VT-x support. VT-x support must be enabled in the host system BIOS. The BIOS settings that must be enabled for VT-x
>     support vary depending on the system vendor. See VMware KB article
>     1003944 for information on how to determine if VT-x support is
>     enabled.

If you can see what CPU you have, you should be able to check if it does support VT-x and how to enable it in the BIOS.

Comment: This may be it, I didn't know I had to do this. Let me check.